# Groups with isomorphic quotients

Tags: gr.group-theory, normal-subgroups

Assume we have a finitely presented group $G$ and a non-trivial normal subgroup N. How can one decide that $G/N$ is isomorphic to $G$ or not? $G$ is given as a presentation and $N$ as a set of words.

Comment: 1) It can be (keyword: "non-Hopfian group"). 2) "one can detect": to make this make sense, you need to say what is the input. Since a necessary condition is that $G/N$ is finitely presented itself, a natural question is whether you can, given a presentation $(S|R)$ and a finite set of words $R'$, determine whether the groups $(S|R)$ and $(S|R\cup R')$ are isomorphic. Of course these are two distincts question according to whether $(G|R)$ is fixed or part of the input.

Comment: Thanks. By detecting I meant a characterization of these groups that one can decide from the presentation.

Indeed, the Wikipedia says

"Equivalently, a group is Hopfian if and only if it is not isomorphic to any of its proper quotients". This gives a name to answer my question!

Comment: "that one can decide from the presentation": this is vague. The presentation of what? of $G$? of $G/N$ that's what I clarified in my previous comment. Besides, wikipedia also provides an example of a non-Hopfian *finitely presented group*, although it's not the first one in history.

Comment: Well, the group G is given by a presentation and one has to decide if it has a non-trivial normal subgroup $N$ such that $G/N$ and $G$ are isomorphic. The problem whether G is Hopfian from the presentation is undecidable as is mentioned in Wikipedia. It seems to me that $G$ is non-Hopfian if and only if it has a non-trivial $N$ such that $G/N$ and $G$ are isomorphic. So this problem I asked (in this comment) is also undecidable.

Comment: In your last comment as you say, it's another problem. It is reasonable to fix a finitely presented group $G$ (with a given generating subset) and to ask whether inputting a finite set of words $R'$ we can algorithmically get the answer whether $G/[R']$ is isomorphic to $G$ ($[R']$ being the normal subgroup generated by $R'$). There are some trivial instances for which the answer is yes (e.g., when $G$ is Hopfian with solvable word problem). Still, it is my guess that there exists $G$ (with solvable word problem) such that this is not decidable.

Comment: I think the following paper by Chiodo might have the answer to your question: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.1792.pdf.